# Kinetic energy in explosions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics

Just to spice up the question, remembering the ray of death star in Star Wars

Assuming that it is thrown against any planet of mass M and with rotation speed V. After the explosion the fragments of the planet are sent by space.

Assuming also that I know the mass and velocity that each of these debris is thrown, the total energy of the explosion will be the kinetic emergence of the debris subtracted by the rotational energy of the planet?

Is the angular momentum conserved?

Comment: angular momentum is conserved but the key quantity here is likely the gravitational energy spent in forming the planet.

Comment: But gravitational energy is just the minimum energy to be able to destroy it. I'm assuming that just like the starkiller the energy is greater than the gravitational one, to the point where the fragments of the planet gain kinetic energy to disperse.

The question is, would just calculating the kinetic energy of the fragments be enough to determine the total energy of the explosion? As well as the conservation of angular momentum what else should I take into account?

Comment: yes you are correct; I misunderstood your question as I have seen a variation of it in a slightly different context.  Presumably you also need the angular momentum of the fragments...  i.e. need $\sum_k I_k\omega^2_k=\sum_k L_k\omega_k$ as the contribution to the rotational energy of the exploding fragments.

Comment: But that's the problem, I'm confused how the law of conservation of angular momentum would apply here.

And would not the rotation of the planet influence the speed at which the debris disperses? I mean, does it have to be subtracted by the kinetic energy of the fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes : angular momentum will be conserved.

No : the final kinetic of the fragments/debris will not be the only energy from the explosion. There is also gravitational potential energy if the fragments move apart; increase in temperature of the debris - perhaps melting some of it; energy spent breaking bonds and deforming the material (this might be negligible if there are few fragments); etc. It would be very difficult to take account of all these contributions in a calculation.

(Incidentally, you cannot say that a planet's rotation speed is $V$ unless you mean speed of angular rotation. Perhaps you mean speed in orbit around the star. Or the speed of a point on the surface, in which case you also need to know the radius of the planet.)

Comment: Another question, if it is a sufficient energy to the point of the planet being pulverized and all its mass dispersed.

To calculate the kinetic energy with which the dust particles are dispersed, would I have to calculate the sum of each particle? Or could it just replace the mass of the planet in the kinetic energy equation? (Assuming the speed is known)

Comment: Yes, you would have to sum the KE of each particle.

Comment: I see
could you give an explanation of why I can not use the total mass of the planet once it is fully ejected? Would not the result be the same?

Just so I do not miss the test

Comment: Sorry, reading your comment again I think I misunderstood. If every fragment from the explosion had the same speed $v$ then the total KE of all fragments is $\frac12Mv^2$ where $M$ is the mass of the planet. (This assumes the fragments are not rotating.)

Comment: So if they had different speed would I have to calculate the kinetic energy of each particle?

Comment: That's right. Or do you think there is some easier way?

Comment: No, last question, How does the conservation of angular momentum influence the kinetic energy of the fragments? And how it influences an explosion

Comment: You know how angular momentum works : if you move the parts of a rotating body further apart, they get slower. A cloud of rotating debris will have a slower rotation rate than the dense planet it was formed from.